# Oracle SQL VARCHAR column with Line break

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried this:

```
update MESSAGE set TEXT = 'The following ' || CHAR(13) || CHAR(10) || 'has been disapproved'
        where TITLE = 'REQUEST_DISAPPROVED';commit;
```

And:

```
DECLARE
   msg VARCHAR2 := 'The following ' || CHAR(13) || CHAR(10) || 'has been disapproved';
BEGIN
   update MESSAGE set TEXT = :msg
            where TITLE = 'REQUEST_DISAPPROVED';
END;
```

And:

```
var this_is_a_variable varchar2(3000); 

exec :this_is_a_variable := 'The following ' || CHAR(13) || CHAR(10) || 'has been disapproved';
update MESSAGE set TEXT = :this_is_a_variable where TITLE = 'REQUEST_DISAPPROVED';
```

Each gives a variety of errors, I believe this is merely a syntax problem. 
The ultimate goal is when a plain text e-mail generated from this message, it will have appropriately placed line breaks.

Is this possible?

Comment: What error message? Does it work without the CHAR(13)? The second form does not use the msg at all.

Comment: Fixed the 2nd form, it was supposed to use the `:msg` variable. I will try with `CHR(10)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the CHR function and the new line character results in the desired outcome.

```
UPDATE MESSAGE
SET TEXT = 'The following '
  || CHR(10)
  || CHR(10)
  || 'has been disapproved'
WHERE TITLE = 'REQUEST_DISAPPROVED';
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error.  It's `CHR(10)` not `CHAR(10)`.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with above answers, its a syntax error CHAR(10) is incorrect function, please use CHR(10) instead:

for e.g.

```
SELECT 'The following ' || CHR(10) || CHR(10)|| 'has been disapproved' SMS_TEXT
FROM dual;
```